What is the purpose of the base inductor on this Class C amplifier?
This Pixie III 7 MHz transceiver uses Q2 as a Class C amplifier.  What is the purpose of L1?

The article only says

The value of RF choke L1 is not critical. Since little current passes through it most any molded or surface mount device will work. Wind your own with an FT37-43 toroid with 15 turns of wire.

but doesn't explain what it's function is.
Normally, in a Class C amplifier, you want to pull the base down to ground.  If that's the goal, why use an inductor and not a resistor?

When the key is down, it is pulled to ground.
The base generates negative DC voltage, by rectification.  A resistor would drop voltage, and thus the base wouldn't be grounded.
But realize ground itself is arbitrary here.  In general, we want some bias voltage at the amplifier input terminal.  Along with input amplitude, bias determines conduction angle, linearity, etc.  (Linearity might indeed still be a concern for a class C amplifier -- less linear than class A/B, certainly, but far from all-or-nothing.)
The inductor also dissipates less signal power, as it is reactive rather than resistive.  If a lot of bias current must be sunk, at low voltage drop, and particularly if high efficiency or gain is desired, an inductor would prove beneficial over a resistor.
We can even have both: an LC network to decouple the AC and DC paths, and a resistor to supply DC bias.
It seems that, for this case, they wanted to force the bias voltage to zero, perhaps to increase conduction angle given that the input amplitude is fairly high (should be at least a few volts from Q1 emitter, I think?).
I'd have to test variations to see if that's actually beneficial, but I think it's pretty clear they weren't after top-notch performance here in the first place, given the frequency-keyed oscillator (which will affect its amplitude too), the non-single-supply op-amp, and generally poor receiver behavior (strong side-tone output, unbalanced mixer, no AGC, no selectivity beyond the antenna and tuning network, etc.).  It would be better to read such circuits, not as a practical way of doing things, but "someone did this and it seemed to work".

LOL to "someone did this and it seemed to work".  It's all too often the reason.
